# Column referencing in VBA using sheet().Range().Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to avoid copy and paste in order to dramatically speed up a Macro (previously taking two minutes to run).  I am trying to reference four entire columns in Sheetx(A,B,J,L) and have them display in sheety(A6,B6,C6,D6).

I have tried a number of variations of

Sheets("Sheety").Range("A6:A,B6:B,C6:C, D6:D").Value = Sheets("Sheetx").Range("A:A, B:B, J:J, L:L").Value

Also, for sheets("sheety") I tend towards Active.Sheet or Sheets(B) as I have used the index number for the sheet ie

For B = 31
31 being the index number for the real sheet.

I have been searching for answers for the last hour.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want `A6` to go to `A6` or `A1` in the other sheet??

Comment: The entire column of A1 on sheet x to A6 down of a sheety, if that makes sense.  When I say the entire column I mean all cells that have contents which can vary from 900 rows to 20000 rows.

Comment: `Sub Testy3()

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A7:A16").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value

End Sub` @Gary's Student  This one works for the specified range but I'm after something that references the whole column upto the last cell containing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if something like this:

```
Sub Testy3()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & N).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6")
End Sub
```

works for you.

If all the columns in `Sheet1` have the same number of rows, then you don't need to re-calculate **N** for each column.

Comment: That does the trick, I am a bit dim though, how would I use one variable N for the four columns in question ( I have had to duplicate the code four times created O,P,Q variables.

Comment: @Pablo84  If all the columns in `Sheet1` end on the same row, then you don't need separate variables

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know its been a while but that did the trick.